# How to start NavigationController after button press in rubymotion

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, rubymotion

I'm trying a simple app in RubyMotion for the first time. I simply want to be able to click a button and then start a `UINavigationController`

Steps:
 - User presses a button
 - screen moves to left and new navigation starts

I can do this fine if I start the navigation from the first view itself but I want to be able to start it at button push.

Here is what I have so far

**AppDelegate:**

```
#below commented line starts the navigation from the first view
#navController = UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(HomeController.alloc.init)
@window.rootViewController = HomeController.alloc.init
true
```

**HomeController:**

```
  def viewDidLoad
    self.title = "ONE"
    button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeRoundedRect)
    button.frame = [[15,300], [280,50]]
    button.setTitle("Move to next view", forState: UIControlStateNormal)
    button.addTarget(self, 
                     action: "startNavigationOne:",
                     forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside)

    view.addSubview(button)
  end

  def startNavigationOne (sender)
   #what can I do here to start the navigation?
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested this code and writing from memory, but it should work.

```
def startNavigationOne (sender)
  # Create your next controller and its navigation controller
  next_controller = UIViewController.alloc.initWithNibname(nil, bundle: nil)
  nav = UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(next_controller)

  # Now set it as the root view controller
  UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window.rootViewController = nav

  # The current UIViewController will be deallocated when this method exits
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your appliation Navigation Based app Using Following 3 Steps in appDelegate.m file

Step 1 :First create a RootViewController

```
ViewController *rootViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Step 2 : Create A Navigation Controller with RootviewController

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
```

Step 3: Add Navigation Controller to Window's Root ViewController

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
```

Now to Navigate On button Click write this

Create your viewController object which you want to Push/Navigate

```
ViewController *startNavigationOne = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Push that view using Navigation Controller

```
[self.navController pushViewController:startNavigationOne animated:YES];
```

Comment: At step 3 when I run the app it already has a bar on top of the screen meaning it already has navigation. I dont' want this. I want the bar on top to appear only when I click the button

Comment: then you need to write this [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES]; to show and  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES]; to hide

Comment: As this is not ruby code, it can be easily translated into ruby. The good info about this post is the correct usage of the self.pushViewController method.